# Can I set the launcher to only be visible when I'm on the desktop?

Tags: unity, launcher, customization

I'd like to **show** the Launcher when I am on my desktop and **hide** it when an application is running. How can I personalize it?

Answer (score 1):

You can autohide Launcher..

Go to

**Desktop Screen ==> RightClick ==>Change Desktop Background => Behaviour (Tab) ==> Autohide [ON]**

That's it...

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to do exactly what you are asking as Unity is designed to look the same on every system (good promotion tactic), however you can get the unofficial 'Unity Tweak Tool' on a 12.10 PPA:

Press Ctrl + Alt + T on your keyboard and then run the following commands in order:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

or you can upgrade to the Ubuntu 13.04 Release Candidate by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T on your keyboard and typing in:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

and then getting the tool with:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Unfortunately the tool isn't available in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS due to some technical difficulties.

If the tool doesn't do what you want it to, try learning the C/Vala/C++(/NUX) programming languages and then [changing Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/) so it does what you want. That is half the point of open-source after all.